# HTTP Logic App Trigger via SQL Script Task

Tags: c#, ssis, http-post, azure-logic-apps, script-task

Triggering HTTP Post Request in Logic Apps from Script Task in SSIS. It works when I run it locally but not on the server via sql agent. Its running successfully in the server but not triggering the logic app. Any ideas on what I am missing?

```
 public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string RefreshLink = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["$Project::LogicAppHttp"].Value);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RefreshLink);
            var postData = "thing1=hello";
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            Dts.Log(ex.Message, 99, null);
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }
```

Comment: Could you be getting an Exception.  The code above always sets the Dts.TaskResult to Success even if you get an exception because it is the last line to be executed.  Set that at the end of the 'Try' and maybe you will get a result with the exception pointing to why it is not working.

Comment: You are correct! I realized that as well once I looked at the code a bit more. It finally ran on the server and failed as expected as there was a port that needs to be open on the server.

Comment: Could you answer to your own question ?